# Pass variable value to script from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I like the shred command so instead of using the 'rm' command I prefer shred. I would like to create a bash script in /usr/bin, say we will call it "shredder" so that if I want to shred a file (i.e. test.txt) all I have to do is type:

shredder test.txt

And the bash script does it for me. I made a bash script like this but can't figure out how to pass it the fie name in terminal before I run it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
read fle
shred -n 3 -zvfu $fle
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `shred -n 3 -zvfu $1`.

Answer (score 6):

you can use script in following manner

```
#!/bin/bash
clear    
for var in "$@"
  do
    shred -n 3 -zvfu "$var"
  done
```

Or A shorter version

```
#!/bin/bash
clear    
for var
  do
    shred -n 3 -zvfu "$var"
  done
```

Run your script followed by the file name you want to shred.
You can use multiple file separated by space.

Answer (score 3):

Bash uses special environment variables for handling arguments/parameters

1. $0 : the scriptname itself
2. $# : Total number of arguments
3. $1 : first argument
4. $2 : second argument

and so on

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo name of script is $0
echo first argument is $1
echo second argument is $2
echo number of arguments is $#
```

The output of this program will look like:

```
bash /tmp/test.sh one two three
name of script is /tmp/test.sh
first argument is one
second argument is two
number of arguments is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create an alias for "shredder" by running the following command:

```
echo 'alias shredder="shred -n 3 -zvfu"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now, source your `.bashrc` file to apply the changes (reset bash shell):

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Finally, you can use the "shredder" command to delete files.